# JavaFX adding abstract class object to arraylist

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, javafx

I am making a JavaFX application to keep track of company inventory. A user can add/delete/modify parts and products.

the part and product classes have attributes and getter and setter methods, however the Part class is Abstract -

```
Product              Part<Abstract>

id                   id
name                 name
price                price
min                  min
max                  max
get/set              get/set
```

I have 3 arraylists that are displayed in a tableview -

```
private ObservableList<Part> allParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ObservableList<Part> associatedParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

How can i add new Parts to the allParts and associatedParts arraylists when Part is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated?

How do i associate certain Parts with certain Products? Each product must always have one or more associated Part.

Comment: You can put any subtype of `Part` in the list. If `Foo` _is a_ subtype of `Part`, then if an instance _is a_ `Foo`, it _is a_ `Part`. This is the heart and soul of inheritance. See the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: Java abstract list may be a perfect example. For example: `List<String> list = new ArrayList();` and `List<String> list2 = new LinkedList();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments subclass `Part` to use its instances.
Also subclass `Product` to add `private ObservableList<Part> associatedParts = FXCollections.observableArrayList();` to it, to track associated parts.